# Angular JS: Can't load templates in rails project

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm having a problem loading my templates in our staging environment and it seems that's only stopped working in the last few days:

```
GET /geo/index.html 404 (Not Found)
```

Interestingly, I'm not getting any console errors in development, only in staging environment.

I'm using 'angular-rails-template' gem and included in my application.js:

```
//= require angular/angular (Minified Angular.js file)
//= require angular/angular-resource (Minified Angular.js resource file)
//= require angular-rails-templates
//= require_tree ../templates
```

In my app.js file:

```
'use strict';

var geo = angular.module('geo', [
  'ngRoute',
  'templates'
]);

//Set Config and Routes analytics
geo.config(function ($routeProvider) {

  $routeProvider

// Geo Home
.when('/', {
  templateUrl: 'geo/index.html',
  controller: 'GeoController',
  title: 'geo'
})

.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});

});
```

I'm really struggling to understand why it would have just broken all of a sudden and not render the templates in the templates directory.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: maybe the location of index.html is not `geo/index.html`?

Comment: try restart your rails

Comment: @wizztjh Have multiple times mate! No dice.

Comment: did you solve this? For the lift of me I cannot figure out how to get `angular-rails-templates` working - also with "Failed to load template: blah.html"